# Intentservice doesn't call runnable

Tags: android, accelerometer, runnable, intentservice

I have following code in intent service (I have to use intentservice)

```
//TIME HANDLER
    Log.i("start", "start getting data acc & gps");
    //Register listeners and start getting data
    //
    // ACC:
    onStartAcc();
    //

    handle_lower.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i("stop getting data", "STOP");
            //Stop listeners
            //
            // ACC:
            onStopAcc();

            //==========================================================================
            //HERE IS CALCULATING STATUS
            //
            status.calculateState();
            //==========================================================================
        }


    }, Constants.TIME_ACCELEROMETER_GETTING);
```

and it doesn't call runnable, no log is shown and accelerometer receiver is not unregistered.

I don't know why this happens. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have to use intentservice

You have to **not** use `IntentService` for this use case.

> it doesn't call runnable, no log is shown and accelerometer receiver is not unregistered

Once `onHandleIntent()` returns, the `IntentService` shuts down and goes away. Therefore, you cannot register listeners, fork threads, use poorly-implemented timing systems, etc. in an `IntentService`.

You are welcome to use a `Service`. Convert your `postDelayed()` stuff into a `ScheduledExecutorService` (so your work is done on a background thread), and make sure that you call `stopSelf()` at the appropriate point to shut down the service.

Comment: one remark:i believe that it shuts down when there are no pending requests in the internal Message queue

Comment: @pskink: Correct, though that does not really change the suitability of `IntentService` in this case.